# Why can't I create a function named pow()?

Tags: c

This is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main() { 
  int a,b; 
  int pow(int,int); 
  printf("Enter the values of a and b"); 
  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b); 
  printf("Value of ab is %d",pow(a,b)); 
} 

pow(int c,int d) { 
  return c*d; 
}
```

I didn't include `math.h` in my program. I am using the gcc compiler. I am getting the following error

```
ex22.c: In function `main': 
ex22.c:6: error: conflicting types for `pow'
```

After searching I came to know there is a pow function in `math.h`. I am not including `math.h`, but still I am getting the error. How come?

Comment: That looks like a gcc error, which means that there is probably more lines in the error output. Please edit the question to include the *complete* error log.

Comment: Try `int pow(int c,int d)` instead of `pow(int c,int d)`

Comment: Why do you wish to create a function with the same name as a library function? That's generally a recipe for disaster.

Comment: This code actually *crashes* my compiler (`clang-503.0.40`), so I guess one possible answer is "because they didn't expect you to try to do that".

Comment: I get a slightly different error (from gcc 4.7.2): _foo.c:5:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘pow’ [enabled by default]_, which is slightly more informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to use an identifier for your own function that is also the name of a C standard library function, regardless of whether you've included the header for that standard function. The C Standard forbids this explicitly unless the function is declared `static`, and compilers may treat such functions specially (in the case of e.g. `pow(x, 2)`, by emitting code for `x*x` instead of a function call).

Comment: but the vice versa is not true I guess. If I use a library function and if I am not including the corresponding header file, I will be getting the error rit?

Comment: @sameer Then you get a warning for not declaring the function.

Comment: quibble: The standard says "All identifiers with external linkage in [the standard library] are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage." and "Each identifier with file scope [in the standard library] is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included." That would seem to imply that all would be well if `pow` were declared `static` since `math.h` is not included. Also, gcc is ok with that if you specify `-fno-builtin-pow`.

Answer (score 0):

This one works, but with warning:

`warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'pow' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
int pow (int,int);
    ^
test.c:3:5: note: 'pow' is a builtin with type 'double (double, double)'`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int pow (int,int);

int main(void) {
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the values of a and b");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("Value of ab is %d", pow(a,b));
}

int pow(int c,int d)
{
    return c*d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: No warnings but crazy programming

```
#define pow stupidpow
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the values of a and b\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("Value of ab is %d", pow(a,b));
}

int pow(int c,int d)
{
   // count c^d
   printf("\nAns is \n");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use PowInt in stead of pow.
That is safer and never gives any confusion.

```
int PowInt (const int m, const int e)
{
int i, r;

        r = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= e; i++)
            r = r * m;
        return( r );    
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "Why can't I create a function named pow()"?